# Exception on Java.time Package

Tags: java, database, hibernate, exception, orm

I'm using Hibernate 5.0.0CR1 for it's ability to use the JDK8 time package, but I'm getting an exception at this code when I try to persist an entity. Can someone tell me what is happening, and how to fix it? I'm using the `EntityManager` API's.

Mapping:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "Creation_Date", nullable = false)
private final ZonedDateTime creationDate;
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property
```

Comment: That exception message says it all. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: @Raedwald Isn't hibernate 5.0.0CR1 supposed to be compatible with `java.time`? Why doesn't it just convert it to the proper database format?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the creationDate's type. The error is specific enough about what the Temporal annotation needs i.e. either a a java.util.Date or a java.util.Calendar property whereas ZonedDateTime implements neither. Do not confuse the java.time.temporal.Temporal interface which ZonedDateTime implements with the javax.persistence.Temporal annotation.

Use one of them and it will work.

The [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Temporal.html) on Temporal are clear enough about it as well:

> This annotation must be specified for persistent fields or properties
>   of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar. It may only be
>   specified for fields or properties of these types.

I recommend using a date field over a calendar one because a calendar basically provides getter and setter for the date fields and it and it brings a slight overhead.
Only use Calendar when you actually need to perform date/time calculations, or to format dates for displaying them to the user.

**Solution example**:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "Creation_Date", nullable = false)
private Date creationDate;
```

Comment: Isn't the point of the 5.0.0CR1 version that I can use the `java.time` with my classes? Why do I need to change it to the old (much worse) date format?

Comment: No one is forcing you to use the Temporal annotation. It's behaviour is as i described. Also remember when persisting to use one of TemporalType.DATE , TemporalType.TIME orTemporalType.TIMESTAMP. You are free to map your column to another field or you can write your own converter for ZonedDateTime. There have been talks of adding support to the @Timestamp for the new Java 8 time classses. Hibernate did indeed add support for Java 8 date and time types but i haven't seen any usage on it yet https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue while I was converting from Date to ZonedDateTime, you can apply annotation '@CreationTimestamp' instead of  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) and it will work;

```
@CreationTimestamp
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
private final ZonedDateTime creationDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the @Temporal annotation with java.time.* classes. There is an explicit mapping:

- Instant, ZonedDateTime, ... -> TIMESTAMP
- LocalDate -> DATE
- LocalTime, OffsetTime -> TIME

This is all explained here: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-date-time